# Convert vector into a triangular matrix

Tags: vector, matrix

I have a vector of 874! elements, which I want to turn into a triangular matrix (i.e. the top right hand corner of a square matrix).

Example Input:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Example Output:

```
1 2 4 7
  3 5 8
    6 9
      10
```

Blanks could be filled with NAs. I'd prefer if the matrix were this way around.

Comment: Are the differences between consecutive elements at the same row/column necesarily incremental?

Comment: I have edited my answer with a better calculation of the square matrix dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which programming language do you want to use neither do I understand which order do you want your numbers to be stored in.

You should consider that having *N* elements, if you want to generate an square matrix its dimensions (*n* rows and columns) are given by:

```
N = (n*(n+1))/2
```

So a first approach (you should consider if your input vector has x^2/2 elements) in Python could be:

```py
from math import sqrt

x = range(1,25+1) # This is your input vector
N = len(x) 

#N = (n*(n+1))/2 # Number of elements being stored in a triangular matrix.
n = (-1.0+sqrt(1.0+8.0*N))/2.0 # Solve the equation given by the previous relation.
n = int(round(n)) # Making it integer...

while (n*(n+1))/2 < N: # ... losing precission so we should use the first n being able ...
    if (n*(n+1))/2 < N: # ... to store your vector is used.
        n += 1    

res = [[0]*n for i in xrange(n)] # Here, we create a n*n matrix filled with zeros.
x = x[::-1] #Reverse the input so it can be consumed using pop (O(1) each extraction)

for j in xrange(n): # Fill the empty matrix following the triangular pattern and using...
    if not x:
        break
    for i in xrange(j+1):
        if not x:
            break
        res[i][j] = x.pop() # The elements from your input vector.

for row in res: # Let's print the result!
    print(row)
```

The idea is to consume *x* filling the square matrix (*res*) with is values in the right order. This can easily done once you now your target matrix dimesions.